Find the equivalent resistance between the points $A$ and $B$ on a 3D cube
In the figure shown below, find the equivalent resistance.
I know I should add my attempt but I don't know how to approach these type of problems. This isn't the standard series-parallel combination and I am facing a lot of difficulty in doing this question.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Are you familiar with Mesh analysis or Nodal analysis? It looks like there are 32 nodes in the circuit. One would then proceed to write down 32 linear equations and then solve them. Due to symmetry of the circuit, multiple noeds will have the same voltage and hence most of your 32 equations will be of the form $V_i = V_j$ which will significantly reduce the number of equations to solve. Apart from that, if two nodes are at the same potential, you can remove any wire connecting them since current wasn't flowing through it anyway. Try these methods and update your question using [edit] results.

I have just passed grade 12, and I fear I do not know those analysis....but you have mentioned that, due to symmetry, we can remove some wires... I have seen my ex-teacher doing this in other questions, but I am not that well versed in circuits, so I am having a problem with figuring out what to remove and what not. @AJN

When we were learning series and parallel resistances, my high school physics teacher posed (roughly) this question, what is the resistance of a cube with a one ohm resistance on each edge?  This was something to get us thinking there might be problems that cannot be solved using the easy two dimensional techniques.  We learned how to address problems like that, I think it was second semester physics in engineering school.

Nodal analysis like AJN mentioned in the comments is best way to get an exact solution. In the real world you would do this analysis in a computer with python for example and that would permit you to easily change the model to evaluate different behaviors and optimize. In my experience, professors like trick problems where with a lucky approach you can greatly simplify a problem (making them look smart). But in real life, knowing the robust tools to handle non-academic problems is more important.
So especially in academia look for symmetry and ways to mentally simplify the object. Also looking at ways to estimate can get you close to a guess and often send you on a path to a solution.
To estimate, majority of the resistance is occurring in the 3 legs contacting A and B. The current is much lower in the rest of the cube, and will contribute to the resistance but much less. For r being the side length of the cube. Three 1/3r ohm resistors in parallel = 1/9r ohm and putting A and B in series gives 2/9r ohm. So the true value of the whole cube will be greater than 2/9r and probably less than 4/9r ohm.
Also note that there is specifically an electrical engineering stackexhange. The guys over there have probably suffered similar academic problems and would be able to give more specific guidance.

As was mentioned in comment from AJN, you can use symmetry to simplify this problem.
I started by considering a simpler problem: a cube with each edge connected by a resitor of value r. Two opposite corners are A and B. Total 8 corners and 12 edges.
A is connected to three other corners by a single resistor each. By symmetry each of these corners, call them A1, A2 and A3, are at the same voltage and can be connected with wires without changing anything. Likewise for B. So from A to (A1A2A3) you have three resistors in parallel, total resistance is $\frac{r}{3}$. Likewise from B to (B1B2B3) you have $\frac{r}{3}$. That leaves 6 resistors which connect (A1A2A3) to (B1B2B3), These are effectively in parallel and so have a total resistance of $\frac{r}{6}$.
That means the total resistance between opposite corners A and B is $\frac{5r}{6}$.
You can do a similar, but more complicated analysis for your original question.
You will end up having to do mesh (current loop) analysis after you have simplified the layout. (There will be four loops)
My attempt at a solution:
If you do a similar analysis on your original question you should end up with a circuit something like this:

Doing a loop current analysis you end up with two simultaneous equations (because of symmetry $i_3=-i_5$ and $i_2=-i_4$).
For example in loop $i_2$ the voltage $ -i_2*\frac{r}{2} = i_2*\frac{5r}{6}+i_1*\frac{5r}{6}-i_5*\frac{r}{2} $. (Current right to left is positive, current left to right is negative)
When you solve them you can find $i_2$ and $i_3$ in terms of $i_1$ and then the resistance between A and B.
I got it to be $\frac{71}{66} r$ ( where r is the resistance of the side of a small cube), but I may have made an error that I didn’t detect. (I found a few of them)
@EricNutsch estimate is good (except he used r as the resistance on the side of a large cube.) Using that figure my result comes out to be 0.359, which is right within his estimate.
